# Stripping (XML?) markup from a document using python

Tags: python, xml, markup

I've file which contains name of scientist in following format
   `<scientist_names>
   <scientist>abc</scientist>
   </scientist_names>`
i want to use python to strip out name of scientists from above format How should I do it??
I would like to use regular epressions but don't know how to use it...please help

Comment: This looks like XML. Check out [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

Comment: If I have such continuos lines `<scientist>abc</scientist><scientist>xzz</scientist>` then can anyone please tell me fastest way to extract data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted, this appears to be xml. In that case, you should use an xml parser to parse this document; I recommend lxml ( http://lxml.de ).

Given your requirements, you *may* find it more convenient to use SAX-style parsing, rather than DOM-style, because SAX parsing simply involves registering handlers when the parser encounters a particular tag, as long as the meaning of a tag is not dependent on context, and you have more than one type of tag to process (which may not be the case here).

In case your input document may be incorrectly formed, you may wish to use Beautiful Soup: [http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing XML](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Parsing%20XML)

Comment: @user997704: You don't. Learn to use the right tool for the job.

Comment: I would like to use but I'm not getting Quickstart guide to learn SAX

Answer (score 2):

This is XML and you should use a XML parser like `lxml` instead of regular expressions (because XML is not a **regular** language).

Here is an example:

```
from lxml import etree
text = """<scientist_names> <scientist>abc</scientist> </scientist_names>"""

tree = etree.fromstring(text)
for scientist in tree.xpath("//scientist"):
    print scientist.text
```

Answer (score 2):

**DO NOT USE REGULAR EXPRESSIONS!** (all reasons well explained [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1132524))

Use an xml/html parser, take a look at [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Comment: You might want to have a look into BS sources. You'll be surprised.

Comment: @thg435: You are comparing apples with oranges. No-one should write their own custom parsing using regexes, because that approach is fragile. Beautiful soup uses regexes to deal with malformed markup as part of an effort to write one, well-tested, well-designed library to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an simple example that should handle the xml tags for you

```
#import library to do http requests:
import urllib2

#import easy to use xml parser called minidom:
from xml.dom.minidom import parseString
#all these imports are standard on most modern python implementations

#download the file if it's not on the same machine otherwise just use a path:
file = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.somedomain.com/somexmlfile.xml')
#convert to string:
data = file.read()
#close file because we dont need it anymore:
file.close()
#parse the xml you downloaded
dom = parseString(data)
#retrieve the first xml tag (<tag>data</tag>) that the parser finds with name tagName,
#in your case <scientist>:
xmlTag = dom.getElementsByTagName('scientist')[0].toxml()
#strip off the tag (<tag>data</tag>  --->   data):
xmlData=xmlTag.replace('<scientist>','').replace('</scientist>','')
#print out the xml tag and data in this format: <tag>data</tag>
print xmlTag
#just print the data
print xmlData
```

If you find anything unclear just let me know

Comment: error while executing `data = file.read()` str object has no atrribute 'read'